# How do i allow only one (dash or dot or underscore) in a user form input using regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

**I'm trying to implement a username form validation in javascript where the username**

- can't start with numbers
- can't have whitespaces
- can't have any symbols but only **One dot or One underscore or One dash**

*example* of a valid username: the_user-one.123
*example* of invalid username: 1----- user

i've been trying to implement this for awhile but **i couldn't figure out how to have only one of each allowed symbol**:-

```js
const usernameValidation = /(?=^[\w.-]+$)^\D/g 
console.log(usernameValidation.test('1username')) //false
console.log(usernameValidation.test('username-One')) //true
```

Comment: Since your question is about form validation, am I correct in thinking you are using the HTML `pattern` attribute? Or are you doing your validation via JavaScript? Please add this distinction to your question. The best answer to your question really depends on it.

Comment: i'm doing the validation via javascript not HTML pattern

Comment: Apologies. I really should have realized that from the title and the tags. My mind somehow made a strong assumption about HTML when thinking about forms and regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the start:

```
^(?!\d|.*?([_.-]).*\1)[\w.-]+$
```

This will check if the string

- neither starts with digit
- nor contains two `[_.-]` by use of [capture and backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EefvZf/1) (more explanation on the right side)

Answer (score 2):

Preface: Due to my severe carelessness, I assumed the context was usage of the HTML `pattern` attribute instead of JavaScript input validation. I leave this answer here for posterity in case anyone really wants to do this with regex.

---

Although regex does have functionality to represent a pattern occuring consecutively within a certain number of times (via `{<lower-bound>,<upper-bound>}`), I'm not aware of regex having "elegant" functionality to enforce a set of patterns each occuring within a range of number of times but in any order and with other patterns possibly in between.

Some workarounds I can think of:

Make a regex that allows for one of each permutation of ordering of special characters (note: newlines added for readability):

```
^(?:
(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\.?)|\.)[A-Za-z0-9]*-?[A-Za-z0-9]*_?)|
(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\.?)|\.)[A-Za-z0-9]*_?[A-Za-z0-9]*-?)|
(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*-?)|-)[A-Za-z0-9]*\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*_?)|
(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*-?)|-)[A-Za-z0-9]*_?[A-Za-z0-9]*\.?)|
(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*_?)|_)[A-Za-z0-9]*\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*-?)|
(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*_?)|_)[A-Za-z0-9]*-?[A-Za-z0-9]*\.?)
)[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Note that the above regex can be simplified if you don't want usernames to start with special characters either.

Friendly reminder to also make sure you use the HTML attributes to enforce a minimum and maximum input character length where appropriate.

If you feel that regex isn't well suited to your use-case, know that [you can do custom validation logic using javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript), which gives you much more control and *can* be much more readable compared to regex, but *may* require more lines of code to implement. Seeing the regex above, I would personally seriously consider the custom javascript route.

Note: I find https://regex101.com/ very helpful in learning, writing, and testing regex. Make sure to set the "flavour" to "JavaScript" in your case.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info, i have been trying to figure it out over since and came to this regex:   
`/^\D([a-zA-Z\d]*)([-._]{1,1})?([a-zA-Z\d]*)?([-._]{1,1})?([a-zA-Z\d]*)?\w$/`   Your work around looks more sophisticated tho 

Comment: That does _not_ solve the problem you described. `\D` allows _any_ non-digit character, _including_ "special characters" that _are not_ dot, dash, or underscore. It allows for only _two_ "special characters", and allows for _multiple_ of the same "special character". `\w` allows underscores.

Comment: Regardless, as you are using JavaScript, I recommend making more use of it instead of using a single regex. It will be more readable, which will make it more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that Bobble bubble's solution is the better fit. Here ia a comparison of the different cases:

```js
console.log("Comparison between mine and Bobble Bubble's solution:\n\nusername             mine,BobbleBubble");
["valid-usrId1","1nvalidUsrId","An0therVal1d-One","inva-lid.userId","anot-her.one","test.-case"].forEach(u=>console.log(u.padEnd(20," "),chck(u)));


function chck(s){
  return [!!s.match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*$/) && ( s.match(/[._-]/g) || []).length<2, // mine
  !!s.match(/^(?!\d|.*?([_.-]).*\1)[\w.-]+$/)].join(","); // Bobble bulle
  
}
```

The differences can be seen in the last three test cases.